# change the postions of tab in UITabbarController

Tags: ios

I have to put 1st tab in lower left corner and other tabs in the middle.Can any one tell how to change the postions of the tabs or change gaps between tabs in UItabbarController

Comment: Using storyBoard - Interface builder  ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the only way to achieve what you want is to use a UINavigationController, then have it always hide the tab tab. You would write your own tab bar controller and UI, and create the tabs as you want. I'm pretty sure there are open source classes that you could use as a starting point.

Comment: actually,i don't want to change the index but the graphical postion. like in tab [a_________b__c_________]. a tab at the start and b,c in the middle.